# SSIS How to Remove a Column That Was Used For Sorting From Pass Though

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to remove a column from Pass Through if it was used for Sorting?

This column is creating Warning Messages as it is not used downstream.

> OnWarning ... The output column "POViaSO.msdyn_purchaseorderid" (748)
> on output "Sort Output" (741) and component "Sort-PO" (692) is not
> subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output
> column can increase Data Flow task performance.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by removing it ? The column is coming from the component before the Sort one right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering the following as your source :

```
SELECT 1 AS ColA, 2 AS ColB, 3 AS ColC
UNION
SELECT 5 AS ColA, 1 AS ColB, 4 AS ColC
UNION
SELECT 6 AS ColA, 4 AS ColB, 3 AS ColC
UNION
SELECT 2 AS ColA, 3 AS ColB, 5 AS ColC
```

[image]

and this is your Sort component :

[image]

If a column is used for sorting within the Sort Transformation, it must be included in the output, and you can't remove it from the "pass-through" directly in that transformation.

You can use this workaround :

Add a Multicast Transformation :

[image]

Then in your destination, don't consider it :

[image]

I checked in SQL Server, it is sorted based on the column B :

[image]

```
ColA    ColC
5       4
1       3
2       5
6       3
```